# UIWebView content size resetting while come back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, contentsize

I am using a `UIWebView` in my `UIViewController`.

After web-view finished loading i am programmatically added a `UIButton` in the bottom of `UIWebView` with extended ContentSize.

When the app enters background and comes back again, it seems as if the `contentSize` that i dynamically added was changed to the content size of `UIWebView` content.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here and/or why this happens? Thanks for your time!

Best Regards,
Gison

Comment: Probably it is not your question's answer but just a tip. It is hard to detect if web view totally loaded. It probably will call your webViewFinishedLoad method more than one time. Depends on web view.

Comment: The problem is for the contentSize i programmatically added was removed while coming back app from background. Any ideia why?

Comment: Maybe you clicked autolayout for your view? unclicked it. I recommend you check this out what methods you call when app goes and back from background.

Comment: I am not using autolayout, and no method call when app goes and back from background Fnally added uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification bserver reset contentSize again while coming back from background.

Comment: ok I m glad if you going to solve this in that way.

Comment: But i am not glad, because i know this is not the right way.

Comment: You better share some code and people easier will help you. It is so hard to find out what happened to your WebView without it

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGFloat padding = 10.0f;
    CGFloat delta = 5;
    CGRect frame =  self.bottomBar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height + padding;
    self.bottomBar.frame = frame;
    
    _webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_webView.scrollView.contentSize.width,
                                                 _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height + frame.size.height + padding +delta );
    self.bottomBar.hidden = NO;
    [_webView.scrollView addSubview:self.bottomBar];
}  This is my code